# Помогите разобраться с FloatingButton android

Tags: android, android-button

Я пытаюсь подключить и внедрить у себя в приложении кастомную кнопку. Вот есть библиотека по ней - [ссылка](https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial). Я использую видео для того чтобы понять как все правильно сделать: [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4Mu6g_M71s). Вот какой у меня получился xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SecondScreenActivity.MainScreen">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    <io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial
        android:id="@+id/fab_but"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:fabGravity="bottom_end"
        app:fabMenu="@menu/fab_menu"
        app:miniFabDrawableTint="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:miniFabTitleTextColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Я вроде все делал как на видео, но по какой-то непонятной причине у меня кнопка находится сразу под `RecyclerView`. Может нужно вместо `LinearLayout` брать какой-то `constraint` или что-то типа того? У меня вроде стоят теги для опускания кнопки к самому низу экрана. И еще какой-то прикол получается - так как кнопка висит сразу под списком, то соответственно когда я нажимаю на эту кнопку то она съезжает немного пониже и выводятся пункты меню этой кнопки. Я думаю что это из-за того что кнопка сразу под списком висит, но может я не прав.

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как ни странно я решил свою проблему)))) Причина была в том что я невнимательно смотрел видеоролик. Вот мой xml разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SecondScreenActivity.MainScreen">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial
        android:id="@+id/fab_but"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:fabGravity="bottom_end"
        app:fabMenu="@menu/fab_menu"
        app:miniFabDrawableTint="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:miniFabTitleTextColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />


</FrameLayout>
```

а вот какой он должен быть:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SecondScreenActivity.MainScreen">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial
        android:id="@+id/fab_but"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:fabGravity="bottom_end"
        app:fabMenu="@menu/fab_menu"
        app:miniFabDrawableTint="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:miniFabTitleTextColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />


</FrameLayout>
```

разметки почти одинаковые кроме одной строки:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

из-за этой строки у меня и была моя проблема. То есть у меня мой `FrameLayout` получал высоту которая соответствовала контенту на макете и соответственно моя кнопка висела под списком и потом сползала когда я нажимал на кнопку.

Я не уверен что мой ответ будет очень полезен, если будет идти голосование за удаление вопроса, то я не буду против его удалить. Но в любом случае может это кому-то пригодится.

Answer (score 2):

`LinearLayout` распологает виджеты только друг за другом, цепочкой, и для вашей задачи действительно не подходит. Так же этот контейнер игнорирует свойство `layout_gravity`, так как к его схеме размещения виджетов оно не применимо.

Смысл же нужного вам позиционирования в том, чтобы поверх одного виджета (RecyclerView) разместить другой (FAB).

Вам нужно выбрать любой контейнер с возможностью наложения виджетов:`FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`. Именно для вашего варианта разметки в вопросе, лучше всего подойдет самый легкий `FrameLayout`, но для более сложных компоновок может потребоваться и более "мощные" контейнеры из списка выше

Comment: вот я заменил по вашему совету свой `LinearLayout` на `FrameLayout` теперь кнопка висит над элементом списка, и дальше при нажатии она перескакивает вниз экрана, как-бы на то место где она и планируется быть. Если бы она вниз не прыгала а висела на одном месте то это было бы очень хорошо. Может есть какой-то способ как это сделать?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Думаю, вам стоит еще раз пересмотреть видео из вопроса и в точности повторить все, что там делают (в частности, там и без моего совета используется FrameLayout, что вы почему то проигнорировали), а когда все будет работать - пытаться что то изменить по своему желанию. Сам я с этой библиотекой не работал и ее "прыжки" для меня такая же загадка. Устанавливать же ее, чтобы в этом разобраться у меня мало желания, как вы понимаете :)

Comment: a вас прекрасно понимаю, моя проблема очень специфическая и решить ее можно только путем прохождения всех этапов туториала. Я буду дальше пробовать, если что-то получится то опубликую свое решение как ответ) спасибо за помощь